# How to add zeros after decimal but still keep the total character length same?

Tags: r

So I know this question would have been my times, but I couldn't find the answer here. I have a bunch of account balances which are like: 85,415.2, 2,690.35, 3,312.768. I want to add zeros to the end of each balance such that the total length of the number becomes 10. If the account balance already had 10 characters, no zeros should be added. I am using sprint("%10f", account_balance) but it doesn't give the right answer..

Comment: You say "after decimal"--are you sure there's always a decimal?

Comment: Did you tried `formatC` function? There is a parameter called `width`. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, I have a huge data set (million+) account balances, didn't check all of them, but what I need is the consistency. At the end of the command, all balances should look the same with 10 characters including decimals and zeros.

Comment: I'm just worried that if you have, say, `"20"` in one row, you'll get `"2000000000"` when you want `"20.0000000"`... but it's a more complicated problem statement if you need to check that the 0s added are *after* a decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Append a string of 10-n zeros where n is a vector of character lengths.  No packages are used.

```
x <- c("85,415.2", "2,690.35", "3,312.768") # test input

paste0(x, strrep(0, 10-nchar(x)))
## [1] "85,415.200" "2,690.3500" "3,312.7680"
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. I get an error saying "invalid 'times' value

Comment: Copy and paste the two lines of code from the answer into a fresh R session and you will see the output shown in the answer.

Comment: invalid times is an error when the 'times' argument is negative.

Comment: The problem is the question.  All questions need to have reproducible input.  Since this was not provided this answer provided it.  If you want to make some different assumptions of what `x` is then display the output of `dput(x)` in the question and if you are using any packages the library statements should shown in the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `str_pad`

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(v1, pad = "0", width = 10, side = "right")
#[1] "85,415.200" "2,690.3500" "3,312.7680"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('85,415.2', '2,690.35', '3,312.768')
```

Comment: @TotalGadha  Not clear about the comment.  Based on the example and description, it gives 10 characters